# How to :insert an entire function into a group (sceneGroup)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I know how to put individual variables into a group but if I were to need a function in the group (so that when I go to make a scene I can insert that entire function into that `sceneGroup` instead of entering each variable in individually) how would I insert that?

Code:

```
function scene:create(event) 
    local sceneGroup = self.view
end

function scene:show(event)
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if (phase == "will") then
     sceneGroup:insert(HomePage()) --- this is what I have tried

    elseif (phase == "did") then

    end
end


scene:addEventListener("create", scene)
scene:addEventListener("show", scene)
scene:addEventListener("hide", scene)
scene:addEventListener("destroy", scene)

return scene
```

scene1.lua:140: ERROR: table expected. If this is a function call, you might have used '.' instead of ':'

This is the error message that I am getting.

I have also tried

```
sceneGroup:insert(HomeGroup) --- this is without the () at the end, at it still fails to work.
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas or know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a function to a display group. Since sceneGroup is a table (like mostly everything in lua), you could declare HomePage like this:

```
sceneGroup.HomePage = function(params)
    -- code for HomePage
end
```

If you want to add a function to the composer through composer.setVariable and composer.getVariable, you have this option.

```
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()

-- locals
local testFunc = function(hello)
    print(hello)
end

-- "scene:create()"
function scene:create( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- create a variable called "myFuntion" with the value of a reference to testFunc
    composer.setVariable( "myFunction", testFunc )
end


-- "scene:show()"
function scene:show( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is now on screen.
        composer.getVariable( "myFunction" )("Testing!")
    end
end

-- Listener setup
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )

return scene
```

This will print "Testing" once the scene is finished animating onscreen.

I do not see a purpose in doing this however. If you want a function for your composer scene, I suggest this method.

```
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()

-- local forward references for FUNCTIONS should go here
local myFunction

-- "scene:create()"
function scene:create( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- init functions here
    myFunction = function(param)
        print("myFunction says "..param)
    end
end


-- "scene:show()"
function scene:show( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is now on screen.
        myFunction("hello")
    end
end

-- "scene:destroy()"
function scene:destroy( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- remove your scene's functions here
    myFunction = nil
end

-- Listener setup
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

return scene
```

As you can see, myFunction can be called throughout the scene with no issue. This example will print "myFunction says hello" once the scene is finished animating onscreen.

Hope this helps,

Joe.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I figured it out now and am making a lot of progression towards my app, I understand how the composer scenes work much better than I did before I asked this question. It seems that functions don't need to be added to sceneGroup at all to make the program work.  :)